# PyQt on Android

Tags: android, python, pyqt

I'm working on PyQt now, and I have to create the application on Android, I've seen the kivy library, but it's too crude.

Is there any way now to run an application on Android made on PyQt?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Android does not support PyQt4. However PyQt5 supported (see [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-scripting/HUbyuYnm3Z8)). However, you could port your application to use [PySide](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PySide). It provides bindings for the Qt4 platform. You can then use [pyside-android](http://thp.io/2011/pyside-android/).

Comment: The "see this" link gives "content unavailable" for me.  Any other links to information on pyqt5 on android?

Answer (score 43):

With the tool [pyqtdeploy](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyqtdeploy) you can deploy a PyQt5 app to:

- Windows
- GNU/Linux
- Mac OS X
- Android
- iOS

[Click here to see pyqtdeploy's documentation](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/pyqtdeploy/). It is a GUI tool that will package your PyQt5 application and compile it for the target platform.

[image: pyqtdeploy gui]

It lets you select various Qt modules to include in the compilation:

[image: pyqtdeploy modules]

On the command-line you would use the `pyqtdeploy-build` command like this:

```
pyqtdeploy-build pyqt-demo.pdy
```

Back in June 2016, [there was a mailing list message that indicated that pyqtdeploy works](https://riverbankcomputing.com/pipermail/pyqt/2016-June/037634.html). It's 2018 as I'm writing this so I assume pyqtdeploy has matured; the latest package version is 2.0.1 which was released on 5 January 2018.

Comment: is their any video tutorial for that?documentation doesn't explain well about possible errors.

Comment: @NimishBansal I can only find videos on Youtube where people use PyInstaller. the closest thing I found was this [tutorial for using pyqtdeploy on Mac OS X](https://plashless.wordpress.com/2014/09/10/using-pyqtdeploy-on-macos-to-cross-compile-a-pyqt-app-for-ios-part-1/).