# PyQt5 and QtWebView on Android

Tags: android, qt, pyqt, pyqt5, pyqtdeploy

First, I have to admit I come back to this topic from time to time, and always I am very confused.

I'd like to use PyQt5 to test wether I could make a test application working on Android. This application should have a web view inside, and here comes the first doubt.

Since [`QWebKit`](https://forum.qt.io/topic/64389/why-did-they-remove-qwebkit-in-qt-5-6) was removed since version 5.6 of Qt, I thought I had to rely on [`Qt WebEngine`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwebengine-index.html), but sadly it is not compatible with mobile platforms.

So I decided to give up util only recently I discovered there's a new player called [`Qt WebView`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwebview-index.html), which according to the official docs

> is useful on mobile platforms such as Android, iOS, and WinRT

I found [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48978939/1979665) which explains how to use it from a Qt/QML perspective, but I still have to find out how to do it from a PyQt perspective.

I do have a [small testing application](https://github.com/umbe1987/webgis) which uses `Qt WebEngine` and it works fine (also as regards to the JS interaction with `QWebChannels`) on desktop.

So after this premise and before diving into the (for me still) obscure world of [`pyqtdeploy`](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/pyqtdeploy/introduction.html), my questions are:

1. Will `Qt WebView` work with PyQt AND Android?
2. If so, should I replace `Qt WebEngine` with `Qt WebView`?

Comment: Closely related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18436340/pyqt-on-android

Comment: @MrEricSir That is not quite right, but thank you anyway for the feedback. basically, I know I can deploy a PyQt5 application to Android and I would use pyqtdeploy for that. However, I am asking about specifically if it is possible to create a WebView with PyQt5 which would be supported by mobile devices (Android in my case), and if the QML/QtWebView stuff is the way to go.

Comment: Just to share that [this post](https://retifrav.github.io/blog/2018/07/14/html-from-qml-over-webchannel-websockets/) is highly related to what I need: communicating to the QML WebView through QWebChannell. Still, it's not PyQt5 based but [this other video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QdetbaHhpNs&list=PLufFYdaWSynGrHS21HG5n9KtshR8YZoGr&index=1) shows how to build a QML app with PyQt5 so I guess it's a matter of studying both sources hopefully. Question number 1 is probably answered, will edit soon.